# Can't resolve remote hostname from Powershell on Server 2008 R2 DC

Tags: dns, powershell, ping

I'm going across a problem in Powershell: I can't ping websites.

Command line works properly but Powershell seems to be unable to resolve remote hostname. In Powershell I can ping local computers in IPv4 and IPv6.

I'm doing this from a domain controller which is connected to a proxy.

Where could the problem comes from?

**UPDATE**

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\> ping 8.8.8.8

Envoi d'une requête 'Ping'  8.8.8.8 avec 32 octets de données :
Réponse de 8.8.8.8 : octets=32 temps=27 ms TTL=47
Réponse de 8.8.8.8 : octets=32 temps=27 ms TTL=47
Réponse de 8.8.8.8 : octets=32 temps=27 ms TTL=47
Réponse de 8.8.8.8 : octets=32 temps=27 ms TTL=47

Statistiques Ping pour 8.8.8.8:
    Paquets : envoyés = 4, reçus = 4, perdus = 0 (perte 0%),
Durée approximative des boucles en millisecondes :
    Minimum = 27ms, Maximum = 27ms, Moyenne = 27ms
C:\> ping google.fr
La requête Ping n'a pas pu trouver l'hôte google.fr. Vérifiez le nom et essayez
à nouveau.
C:\> nslookup google.fr
Serveur :   UnKnown
Address:  fec0:0:0:ffff::1

*** UnKnown ne parvient pas à trouver google.fr : No response from server
C:\>
```

Comment: So is the problem that name resolution fails (try something like `nslookup superuser.com`), or is the problem that you can't ping outside hosts (try `ping 8.8.8.8` or your ISP's gateway IP)? The two are very different. Also, is this specific to Powershell or is it the same trying from the regular command prompt?

Comment: How do you know you can't? Ie. what result are you getting in PSH (including error messages)?

Comment: **Can't ping Internet** Oh noes, the internet is down! Also, post your code!

Comment: Yeah, ping is not the problem, resolving is. I updated my question. Also, **resolving works from regular command line**.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell couldn't resolve anything because I didn't specified DNS server IP. On a DC you can let a blank field (so the server own IP address is used by Windows), but PowerShell reads the real value (so no DNS IP address).

**You have to set DNS server IP in order to PowerShell to work.**

[image]